# Why the loop only run one time?

Tags: c++, while-loop, ofstream

I tried to do a phone Sys and I used a while loop in the main{}. I don't know why it only runs one time, it suppose to run infinite time unless I give it command to stop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


void record(string name, int phoneNum, int count);

// main
int main() {
    cout << " Welcome to use the Phone Contact Systerm " << endl;
    string name;
    int phoneNum;
    int count = 0;
    string signToStop;
    cout << " Please enter name and phone number " << endl;
    while ( cin >> name >> phoneNum){
        cout << " If you want to start the program, enter start "     << endl;
        cout << " If you want to quit the program, enter quit " <<     endl;
        cin >> signToStop;
        if (signToStop == "start"){
            record(name, phoneNum, count);
        }
        else if ( signToStop == "quit" ){
            break;
        }
        count++;

    }
}

// record all name info into Name set and record all phone numbers     into PhoneNum set
void record(string name, int phoneNum, int count){
    string Name[] = {};
    int PhoneNum[] = {};
    Name[count] = {name};
    PhoneNum[count] = {phoneNum};

    // now start to record all the info into .txt document

    ofstream phoneFile;
    phoneFile.open("contact.txt");
    phoneFile << name << "  " << phoneNum << endl;
}
```

The result is:

```
 Welcome to use the Phone Contact Systerm 
 Please enter name and phone number 
Molly 5307659229

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I'm guessing but I think the problem is that `5307659229` is too large a number to fit in an `int`, so the read fails and your while loop is not entered. Try testing with a smaller phone number.

Comment: Fwiw, a phone number is not an integer, it's more like a sequence of digits. Storing it into an `int` is not a good idea. The size might be a problem, but just consider that simple problem: how do you record leading `0`?

Comment: Input is failing because a phone number is not an integer. It uses numerical characters, but it is actually a code.

Comment: @gburton This has already been covered in the answers. Use the comments for requesting clarification (and arguing with people) not answering the question please! Also the input isn't failing because the number is a code; the computer doesn't know it's a code.

Comment: @spectras@john I changed it to unsigned long, but it didn't work. 
( As I have commented below)

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ .

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  bit of a timing issue. There were no answers when I made that comment, plus its a bug with one person's code, rather than a stackoverflow compatible question, so I did't give an answer.

Comment: @gburton Actually the answers had been there for half an hour when you posted your comment, and the comments section is not for answering regardless of whether you think the question is on-topic! Thanks

Comment: Oops. I must have been looking at an old version.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try ulong int for the phone number, it might be too long. Also I might add that I am a bit confused, as your function record() has a 3rd argument that has no default argument. Your problem might lie there too. As without a default you need to put the argument in when it is used.

Comment: After I changed it to unsigned long type, it did run through the whole while loop but it won't keep going.

Comment: Here is the result:                                                                                            
 Welcome to use the Phone Contact Systerm 
 Please enter name and phone number 
Molly 5307609869
 If you want to start the program, enter start 
 If you want to quit the program, enter quit 
start

Answer (score 2):

As spectras said, a phone number is not really an integer, and so it's not a "number" in the programming (or even mathematical) sense.

It's more like a sequence of digits; that is, a string.

You have two problems when you try to interpret it as an `int`:

- Your `int` type is too small for the value (this is what's causing your loop to end)
- Leading zeroes are not meaningful (at best, it's used to flip into *octal* mode, which is not what you wanted).

I'd instead read it as a string. You can still validate it later, like "is every character a digit?".

Comment: I changed to unsigned long type instead but it still stuck after the first time of running.                                                                                                                                 Welcome to use the Phone Contact Systerm Please enter name and phone number Molly 5307609869 If you want to start the program, enter start If you want to quit the program, enter quit start –                                        // Then stop

Comment: I did not suggest changing it to `unsigned long`. My suggestion was to read it as the string that it is.

Comment: After I changed it to string, it stuck there,

Comment: Welcome to use the Phone Contact Systerm 
 Please enter name and phone number 
Molly 5307609829
 If you want to start the program, enter start 
 If you want to quit the program, enter quit 
start
// stuck here

Comment: I fixed it! OMG....